# How do i find x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Consider points $A, B, C$ in the following diagram:

[image]

Let $\theta = \angle BAC$.

Then we can write
$\cos \theta = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$ for some value of $x$.

What is $x$?

Comment: $x=\sqrt2\cos(\angle BAC)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$A(1,1), \;\;B(2,3), \;\;C(4,0)$$

then

$$\vec{AB}(1,2),\;\; \vec{AC}(3,-1)$$

and

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\vec{AB}•\vec{AC}}{||\vec{AB}|| ||\vec{AC}||}$$

$$=\frac{1\times 3 +2\times (-1)}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}\sqrt{3^2+(-1)^2}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$$

hence

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{50}}=\frac 15$$

Answer (score 2):

First, calculate the length of each side of the triangle.
$$AB=\sqrt{5}$$
$$BC=\sqrt{13}$$
$$AC=\sqrt{10}$$
Using the law of Cosines :
$$BC^{2}=AB^{2}+AC^{2}-2(AB)(AC)cos(\theta)$$
$$13=5+10-2(\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{10})cos(\theta)$$
$$-2=-2(5\sqrt{2})cos(\theta)$$
$$\frac{1}{5\sqrt{2}}=cos(\theta)$$
so $x=\frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

You can find $x$ by finding the lengths AB,BC,AC, then use LoC to find cos$\theta$ and manipulate to find $x.$